# Convert address to source line in C program

Tags: c

Inside my C program I'm getting function call stack by using **backtrace** and then function names by **backtrace_symbols**, using output of **backtrace**. The resulting strings contain function names and addresses of call initiating code, withing the function. Is there a way to convert those addresses into file names and line numbers? I mean by using C library (Linux only will work) of gcc extensions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: C or C++? Choose a tag.

Comment: What do you actually want? C has no `backtrace` statement. You're talking about debugging? These are two different things.

Comment: Use `libbacktrace`. Here's [the example](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libbacktrace/btest.c) from their repo.

Comment: OP's presumably refering to [this](http://linux.die.net/man/3/backtrace_symbols) API....

Comment: I've written a small util which translates addresses to files, lines and functions. It's based on addr2line. https://github.com/EmilOhlsson/call-trace

Answer (score 5):

Outside of an application, you can convert an address to a source file name and line number using the [`addr2line`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/addr2line.html) utility. (This utility is Linux-specific; Mac OS X has the similar [`atos`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/atos.1.html) utility.)

Within an application, you can use the [`dladdr`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dladdr) function to resolve an address to a shared object and symbol name. I'm not aware of any way to access debug information to get a line number within an application, though.

Comment: I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/jc-gonzalez/27daa915eeb6d79188fd1570ca5a66cb) where I explain the process of getting the source code line number from an address (say, in a crash backtrace). Hope it helps.